# Using PHP to display images from a directory. I want to display it one by one since there are different size.

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is what I came up with

```
    <?php
<<<EOF
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
EOF;
        $images = glob('pfp/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);

        foreach($images as $resource) {
          echo "<img src=\"" . $resource . "\">";
        }
<<<EOF
    </body>
  </html>
EOF;
?>
```

Would there be a better way than this? Ideally I would like for it to look something like [this](http://lsleofskye.tumblr.com/) but I will be satisfied with centered and one by one for a cleaner look. Thank you for your time.

Regards,
NoobPHP

Comment: its not just PHP being used in that reference of yours. It also uses `ajax` on scroll-down to `lazy-load` the images. Your code is right but you cannot control that in PHP to load one by one, you may need to use `javascript/jquery` for that purpose.

Comment: Could you please go in to the detail. I am very new to this stuff!

Comment: `$resource` will give you just the file name, you gotta provide proper path relative to you document root.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the below code, when populating the `img` paths from glob function do not put it in the `src` tag instead put it in other attribute `data-src`. Then after page load has completed use `jquery` code to swap the values of `data-src` into `src` tag one by one.

This is my approach of doing this, there can be many other ways you can do this.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
<?php
        $images = glob('pfp/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
        $i = 1;
        foreach($images as $resource) {
          echo "<img style="display:none;" id='imgLoader_".$i."' data-src=\"" . $resource . "\">";
         $i++;
        }
?>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"><script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("[id^='imgLoader_']").each(function(){
  $(this).delay(500).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-src')).delay(500).show();
 });
});
</script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hey, 
Thanks for the quick reply. It sort of worked but all the images appear to be broken. [Like This](https://i.imgur.com/5oTFyi0.png)

Comment: @NoobPHP check the browser `console` for errors in jQuery Code

Comment: 3loader.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @NoobPHP `loader.png` is a default image I put in the code, you need to replace it with some other default image you want to display instead of the original image.

Comment: I want to display all the images instead of one in a uniformed way.

Comment: @NoobPHP Now the updated code will display images 1 by 1 after certain delay. No default image is required.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain in the ass but I want to display all the images in a grid layout.

Comment: @NoobPHP what was the output of the code? Share a screenahot?

Comment: [OUTPUT](https://i.imgur.com/HYiEjwZ.jpg) I want it to look like [This](https://i.imgur.com/uO6ADRW.png)

Comment: @NoobPHP that you can make via css or you can use any plugin to make the images look like that on UI. ref plugin: http://www.jsonenglish.com/projects/flex/